# Ionic 4 Angular router navigate and clear stack/history of previous page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-router

I'm developing an app using Ionic 4 with Angular router. I would like to navigate to another page and clear the page stack. In Android native, it's something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(NewActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

From what I've read so far, it is possible using `Ionic NavController` but it is deprecating in Ionic 4. I learnt about buttons with `routerLink` but if I'm not mistaken, by using that the app will immediately navigate to the other page. I need to execute some logic before navigating to another page .

For example: Login page. After successful login, the user shouldn't be able to go back to the login page. Also, by clicking the 'login' button, it should call a function to process the login and decide to navigate/not navigate to another page.

Is there any way that I can achieve this with Angular router or do I need to rely on the deprecating Ionic NavController?

Comment: I had to kneel down to `NavController` for this issue. its not fully deprecated, you can still use it. 
or else you can use `ionViewWillLeave()` to empty your stack.

Comment: @Najamussaqib I guess until I found the solution for Angular router, I'll just use `NavController` for now

Answer (score 19):

For example of a login page, which is a **root page** ('/login'), after clicking the login button navigate to a new page like this:

```
onLogin() {
   this.router.navigateByUrl('/profile', { replaceUrl: true }) 
}
```

It replaces the page history entry with a new URL, in this particular case with `'/profile'`. After using a plain `<ion-back-button></ion-back-button>` or the browser's back button, you will not be redirected to the login page but to the preceding page. Let's say your page navigation is like this: **home -> login -> profile**, but the history will remember only **home -> profile**, thus hitting the back button at **profile** page will take you back to home.

For a complete solution, you can combine this with **Angular Route Guards**, to prevent accessing pages based on some conditions (e.g. user is logged in). Hints how to do it can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56804545/7485690).

Comment: my condition is, say I'm in X page and on some condition I navigate to Y page using navigateByUrl. Now from Y page if I click back button, I shouldn't be going to X page. I must be going to some other page. I had a thought like clear navigation stack and add pages to stack programatically, but I did not find any material for that. Can you suggest something ?

Answer (score 8):

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/login', { skipLocationChange: true });
```

Navigates without pushing a new state into history.

https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras

Comment: It works on browser but not when deployed to device. I wonder why.. I need it to work on devices though.

Comment: Update: It actually works but not on root page. Let's say login page is my root page & I'm navigating from login page to home page, it wont work. Login page will still be in history.

Comment: skipLocationChange didn't add the _target_ page in history. It's a matter of context if you want to use `replaceUrl` which remove the current page in history and replace it with the next one, or `skipLocationChange`.

skipLocationChange if great if you know you're navigating to a transient page (say a tutorial screen that show no be navigated back, or a confirmation screen that will auto-redirect).`replaceUrl` is great if you're on a page like login page that should not be navigated back anymore (like after a successful login).

Answer (score 3):

Tried may different approaches but the only one that worked was

`this.navController.navigateRoot('/main/tabs/forms');`

I used it after finishing my authentication process.