# Ionic 4 Delete Page from History (Android)

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, routes

Android devices has back button on menu toolbar. I want to disable the possibility when i login to my app and click on that back button to route on login page.

I want if user click on back button after login then i close the app.
Here is my initial code for routing below.

```
if (token) {
    this.router.navigate(['/main-tabs/tabs/dashboard'])
} else {
    this.router.navigate(['/login']).then();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I've tried many other answers but none of them really works for me. But this one works :

To disallow the login from going 'back' to the authenticated page after logged out, just do something like this in your `app-routing.module.ts` :

```
{
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule',
    canActivate: [LoggedAuthGuard]
}
```

The same for the opposite (to prevent going back into login page with back button) :

```
{
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule',
    canActivate: [NotLoggedAuthGuard]
}
```

And both `LoggedAuthGuard` and `NotLoggedAuthGuard` must implement `CanActivate`. Sample code as below (with `Promise`, but it also works with boolean return) :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate} from "@angular/router";
import {Storage} from "@ionic/storage";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoggedAuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(protected storage: Storage) { }

  async canActivate() {
      return (await !!this.storage.get('access_token'));
  }
}
```

For the `NotLoggedAuthGuard` you just returns the opposite of `LoggedAuthGuard`.

```
async canActivate() {
    return (await !this.storage.get('access_token'));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59368524/7485690) provides a solution for removing the login page from the browser's history by replacing it with a page, that the user was navigated to after successful login. It might be a good and quick solution to:

> I want to disable the possibility when i login to my app and click on
> that back button to route on login page.

### Edit

Basically, adding `replaceUrl: true` would do the trick

```js
   this.router.navigateByUrl('/main-tabs/tabs/dashboard', { replaceUrl: true })
```

Answer (score 1):

What I understood from your question is after user login, You don't want to navigate to login page if back button is clicked. If I understood your question correctly you can try below solution.

> one approach is changing root page

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
```

**or**

> You can achieve this by removing page from stack after successful transition. Place below code inside Login success method

```
let currentIndex = this.navCtrl.getActive().index;
this.navCtrl.push(DestinationPage).then(() => {
    this.navCtrl.remove(currentIndex);
});
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I tried ***navigateRoot*** but it doesn't work for me.
I can't use remove method because i use ionic 4, and it don't have this method

Comment: Where are you take navCtrl variable?

Comment: first `import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';` and then `constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) { }` [here is the doc link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/navigation/NavController/)

Comment: @ABHISHEKG you have linked him documentation to ionic v3, but he states that he's using ionic v4 which does not have the .remove() method anymore.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do like that :

```
  this.platform.backButton.subscribe((()=>{

      if(this.router.url == <insertpathhome>) 
      {
        this.platform.exitApp();
      }
      else{
        //go back
      }
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide me link on documentation about ionic 4 routing?

Comment: Where are you take navCtrl variable?

Comment: I don't want to close the application, i want to see it when i click right android button. (all unused but not closed program (in background))

Comment: I don't understand uyour question , you say : " I want if user click on back button after login then i close the app."  for me   you want to exit app.