# Angular 9 - Routing - Stack History (Clear)

Tags: angular, routes, history, angular9

is it possible with angular 9 routing to manage a scenarious as described below?

There are three page (A, B and C). The user enters in the page A (this is a registration page), then he inserts registration data and he enters in the second page (B) where he must insert a confirmation code. I  would like that from this page the user can go forward (page C) and clear history (page a and b not more accessible with back function), but he can go back on the page A. Is this possible?

A -> B -> C [When in C, A e B not more available]
A -> B -> A [When in B, i can go back in A]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should these pages be unreachable by typing the url directly to browser's address bar after user gets to page C?

Comment: It's an ionic application...no

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 5: remove route history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51427689/angular-5-remove-route-history) And one more [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55057685/ionic-4-angular-router-navigate-and-clear-stack-history-of-previous-page) specific for Ionic with the same answer

Comment: Depending on your requirement, you can use `skipLocationChange` or `replaceUrl`: https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#replaceUrl

Comment: ReplaceUrl covers only the first case. If I am in the page B and I would like to go back page A it's not possible if I use replaceUrl

Comment: Could you create a StackBlitz so we can have something to start with?

Answer (score 1):

There're multiple ways to do this. Two of them are mentioned below:

- You will manipulate the history manually with the native browser `location.history` API.
- Create a service with a `rxjs/subject` that contains the `isRoute` data. Instantiate it in the next page (after `B`). Check the data & perform the route.

Personally, I would prefer the 2nd one. To do this:

1) Generate a service with you preferred name.

2) In the service, create a subject that will store the data of our route (isAllowed) (Initially set to true).

3) In your Page `B` access it as a private class variable in the constructor as well as the router for routing.

```js
constructor(private service: ServiceName, private router: Router) {}
```

4) Check whether the value `isAllowed` is true or not by subscribing to the `isAllowed` `subject`. If not, route to the preferred component.

```js
this.service.isAllowed.subscribe({isAllowed} => {
  isAllowed ? this.router.navigate("component path here") : false
})
```